# how to find character that we want from another txt in c program?

Tags: c, fopen

I need to create a c program to find 'a' character in a sentence from another file. I have done the coding but still, do not get the correct result. What is wrong with my coding? the sentence in the okeya.txt is kazega hukeba okeyaga moukaru, but when I compile the program, the result is "found at 85"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define x_size 80 
int main( void ){

char filename[] = "okeya.txt"; FILE *fp;
char input[ x_size ];
char find  = 'a';
char *poin;
poin=filename;
char *p = input;

if( (fp = fopen( filename,"r" ) ) == NULL ){ printf( "?????????????" );
exit( -1 );
}

while( fgets( input , x_size , fp ) != NULL );
fclose(fp);

while(*poin!= '\0'){
    if(*poin == find){
        printf("\n found at %d .\n", poin-input + 1);
    }
    poin ++;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you traced the execution of this with a debugger, what was the first point at which it behaved differently than you expected?

Comment: Look closely at your code: each time you read a line from the file, you overwrite the previous line read. So at the start of the second `while`, `input` contains the last line of the file. And `poin-input` is pure nonsense, youz can't do anything valuable with that.

Comment: You want to set `poin` to the (last line of) input, not to the filename.